# CompleteableFuture takes longer time when the dataset or load increases

Tags: java, spring-boot, parallel-processing, java-stream, completable-future

I have a requirement where in I need to call 2 apis for 100 users. First API is an oauth api to generate token which takes 2 seconds and the Second call is to actual API using the token generated and that takes around 8-9 seconds. So overall it takes ~10seconds to process  both apis for one user.

I have written following piece of code using CompleteableFuture logic to achieve the parallel execution aiming that total runtime for 100 users will be approximately equal 10-15 seconds. But that’s not happening though!!

If there are just 10 users the overall time to call is 11seonds (time taken for one user is 10seconds).

For 20 users, the overall time is 25 seconds((time taken for one user is 10seconds).

Whereas if there are 100 users (full load) the overall time to call for all 100 users is ~100seconds (time taken for one user is still just 10 seconds)

My question is why there is an increase in overall time despite the fact the calls are happening in parallel mode?

Is there any way to improve this time? I would like to achieve less than 30seconds for 100 users.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

List<CompleteableFutures<listA>> futures = userlist.stream.map(req->CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> methodToCallBothApis(reg.getUserId(),executor))).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<listC> outputList = futures.stream.map(CompleteableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: For a starter, you fix those tons of errors in your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

All the calls are not happening in parallel. The completable future makes the code asynchronous i.e. the main thread doesn't wait for the result to be available. However, parallelism depends on how many CPU cores you have, what is the network bandwidth etc.

In your case, you are making 100 network calls, these calls will be made asynchronous manner but not necessarily in a parallel manner. Thus you may not see the speed you might hope for.

Comment: Make sense! Point missed - All these timelines are based out of my local machine.

Comment: The answer to your question is dependent on what `methodToCallBothApis` is doing for all the time that it is taking.  If it keeps the CPU busy for all of the time, then running the ops in parallel won't save you much time as your code is CPU bound.  If, on the other hand, the op spends most of its time in a wait state waiting for the result of some I/O operation (like a network request), then you should see a  lot of speed up.  If you aren't getting the speed increase that you expect, I would look closely at how the code is waiting for I/O operations to complete.